# How to extract numbers after string using regexp?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to extract the number/numbers that come after the last letter in a given string,  using regexp or any other possible function.

For example, if the string is `'a23kfj879lp999'`, I need only `999` since the last letter in the string is `p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [REGEX_SUBSTR](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php) function:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('a23kfj879lp999', '([0-9]+)$') FROM dual
```

Explanation:

REGEX_SUBSTR simply extracts the first substring from the source string that matches the respective pattern.

Syntax:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, pattern [, start_position [, nth_appearance [, match_parameter [, sub_expression ] ] ] ] )
```

Comment: An explanation would be appreciate

Comment: @Frank [0-9] at first means the output should start with a numerical and + says numerical can occur 1 or more times. $ at the end indicates the string ends there ie. no more characters are present after the occurence of numericals.